# Hibernate <table> tag reverse engineering not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I honestly don't know what else to do. I've looked everywhere, but nothing. Anyone, please, help...

In my reverse engineering file, I'm trying to alter the primary key generator class of one of my tables to "identity". On the database (ms sql 2012) the primary key column is set to identity, but hibernate interprets that as "assigned", so I'm trying to correct that problem.

This is what I put in my reverse engineering xml file:

```
<table name="TITLE">
      <primary-key>
          <generator class="identity"/>
          <key-column name="id"/>
      </primary-key>
</table>
```

And yet, the `<table>` tag does not appear to be taken into consideration. Please, what am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just figured it out. You have to include both the schema AND the catalog. The catalog, in my case, is the database name:

```
<table name="TITLE" catalog="hibernatetest" schema="dbo" class="Jeffery_jump">
      <primary-key>
          <generator class="identity"/>
          <key-column name="id" property="version"/>
      </primary-key>
</table>
```

What's annoying is according to the official hibernate documentation, schema and catalog are optional. Well done, hibernate. Well done.

Comment: I had to do just the opposite. See separate answer

Answer (score 0):

Due to many differences between database and JDBC driver versions, the more general solution is to place a breakpoint in the `org.hibernate.mapping.Table` constructor and then run Maven `hibernate3:hbm2java` in the debugger, and look at the values that are passed down the call chain, e.g.:

```
Table.<init>() line: 105    
Mappings.addTable(String, String, String, String, boolean) line: 188    
MappingsDatabaseCollector.addTable(String, String, String) line: 21
```

In my case I found the `catalog` and `schema` were both `null`. My `<table>` tag was ignored until I *removed* the `catalog` and `schema` attributes.